# Getting an error when running pg_dump on cloud foundry

Tags: linux, postgresql, perl, cloud-foundry

I have a manifest that looks like the below:

```
applications:
  - name: sfcbackups-staging
    memory: 1G
    disk_quota: 4GB
    instances: 1
    buildpacks:
      - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack
      - nodejs_buildpack
    services:
      - sfcstaging-db
```

And an apt.yml that looks like this to install Postgres

```
---
cleancache: true
keys:
  - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
repos:
  - deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main
packages:
  - postgresql-client-11
```

But whenever I try running the command pg_dump (either via node or ssh) I get the following error:

```
Can't locate PgCommon.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PgCommon module)(@INC contains: 
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 
/usr/share/perl5 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 
/usr/share/perl/5.26 
/usr/local/lib/site_perl 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) 
at ./pg_dump line 22.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./pg_dump line 22.
```

There's a couple of things I have tried so far but to no avail:

1. Added the following to my apt.yml

```
  - libdbd-pg-perl
  - libpq-dev
```

2. Running `cpan install DBD::Pg` (via SSH) to see if this would fix the issue however the same error occurs.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also [Unable to install postgresql 9.6 on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/911720/156688)

Comment: You may need to install the package [postgresql-common](https://packages.debian.org/sid/postgresql-common)

Comment: The other issue may be that you need to instruct Perl where to find those files. The apt buildpack isn't running as root and isn't able to write to any of the directories listed in the error output. I don't know Perl though or how you would do that. The files get installed under `/home/vcap/deps/<buildpack-number>/` where in your case `<buildpack-number>` is 0, since apt-buildpack is your first buildpack.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I'm not able to do your first link as I can't run a script before the apt buildpack as far as I know

Comment: @HåkonHægland I also have the same issue with postgresql-common

Comment: @DanielMikusa I can see the pg_dump but cannot see Perl, I think it's using the system Perl which won't have the module. Installing Perl via the apt-buildpack but that doesn't make a difference. I'll look into how I can tell the system Perl to look for the files in the `/home/vcap/deps/0/` folder

Comment: @DanielMikusa adding this to my manifest file works, though not sure how sustainable it is: `env:
  PERL5LIB: /home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/share/perl5/ # Not a fan of this`

Comment: That is the compromise when using apt-buildpack. It cannot install software into the system locations because that would require root, so it installs it into a writable location but requires some environment variables set to ensure that software in non-standard locations is picked up. Manifest or `cf set-env` are two ways to set that, you could also drop in a `.profile` script at the root of your project and `export PERL5LIB=...` there. That get's sourced prior to the app starting.

Comment: Aside from that, you could submit an issue for apt-buildpack and suggest it also set PERL5LIB. It tries to make stuff like this transparent, but it's an uphill battle.